# Economical Way to Filter an Object's Results

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON file and I need to retrieve only the items with the ten highest scores:

My data:

```
{
    "movies" : {
        "eraserhead" : {
               "full_title" : "Eraserhead",
               "votes": 50
         },
        "psycho" : {
               "full_title" : "Psycho",
               "votes" : 90  
         }
    }
}
```

etc, etc for a list of about 50 - 100.

I know I can iterate through and build a list, but I was curious if there's any less processor-intensive way to filter these results based on that property (`movies[title].votes`).

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Unless you're keeping your list sorted, iterating and building the list will be necessary, and plenty easy. Just `break` the loop when you've reached the total.

Comment: ...your title says *"economical"*, but your question says *"easier"*. Which do you want?

Comment: I was thinking less processor intensive than what I had going - the answers answered that. I changed the text though to make that clear.

Comment: I had a mistake in my previous version, but check out the [jsPerf result](http://jsperf.com/reduce-object-of-objects-to-max-property) of my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest would be to make an array, to sort the array and to take the first 10 elements.

```
var myArray = [];
for (var key in movies) {
    var movie = movies[key];
    movie.title = key; 
    myArray.push(movie);
}
var tenFirst = myArray.sort(function(a,b){return b.votes-a.votes}).slice(0,10);
```

[Demonstration (open the console)](http://jsfiddle.net/Xe5g8/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = obj.movies;
var ar=[],k;
    for(k in a){
    if(a.hasOwnProperty(k)){
        var m=a[k];
        m.title = k;
        ar.push(m);
    }
}

    var sorted = a.sort(function(a,b){return a.votes-b.votes;});
    var first10 = sorted.slice(0,10)
```

Comment: If it was parsed from JSON, no need for hasOwnProperty.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting is expensive. Since you stated you want it to be efficient, do this:

```
var result = [],
    len, o;

for (var key in data.movies) {
    o = data.movies[key];
    len = result.length
    if (!len) {
        result.push(o);
    } else if (len < 10) {
        if (o.votes < result[0].votes) {
            result.unshift(o);
        } else {
            while (len--) {
                if (o.votes > result[len].votes) {
                    result.splice(len + 1, 0, o);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (o.votes > result[0].votes) {
        result.shift();
        if (o.votes < result[0].votes) {
            result.unshift(o);
            continue;
        }
        len--;
        while (len--) {
            if (o.votes > result[len].votes) {
                result.splice(len + 1, 0, o);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsperf.com/reduce-object-of-objects-to-max-property

[image]